Optimize Greedy sorting algorithm used for dividing students into groups of 5 with equal gender and school ratios
I have been given a generated CSV file of details of 6000 students in the format :
Tutorial Group,Student ID,School,Name,Gender,CGPA
G-1,5002,CS,John Doe,Male,4.02 (example)
The CSV file is sorted by Tutorial Group, and there are 50 students in each tutorial.

I am to sort these 6000 students into groups of 5 such that :

There should be a good ratio of male and female students in each team
The team shouldn't be dominated by students from one school
The team shouldn't have only low or high cgpa students
Students from a team must be from the same tutorial group (the CSV file is sorted by tut group)

I made a working algorithm using the greedy sorting algorithm to fetch ideal students on each iteration of each team.
Here is how the code works :

Iterate through tutorial groups
Sort tut group by ascending CGPA
Fetch student based on gender and criteria
Flip the sorted tut group (so the CGPA is descending now)
Write team to output.csv and remove team members from tut
Continue until tut is empty and move on to next tutorial group


My Code
# config
school = ['CS', 'EE', 'BS', 'HS', 'COM', 'CE', 'MS', 'SS', 'CEB', 'MED']
team_size = 5
toggle_cgpa = 0

# open and copy records
fp = open('records.csv','r')
pool = [i.replace('\n','').split(',') for i in fp.readlines()][1:]
tuts = [sorted(pool[i:i+50], key = lambda x: x[5]) for i in range(0,len(pool),50)]
fp.close()
fo = open('output.csv','w')

# fetch desirable student from the tutorial group
def fetch_std(tut,gender='MaleFemale',schools=[]):
    global toggle_cgpa
    toggle_cgpa = (toggle_cgpa+1)%2 # switch between 0 and 1
    if toggle_cgpa: tut = tut[::-1] # reverse tut group every other run

    gnd, sch = [], []
    for std in tut:
        if std[4] in gender and std[2] not in schools: return std
        if std[4] in gender: gnd.append(std)
        if std[2] not in schools: sch.append(std)
    if gnd: return gnd[0]
    elif sch: return sch[0]
    else: return tut[0]

# for each tutorial group
for tut in tuts:
    # prioritize three of majority gender
    m_tut = f_tut = 0
    for std in tut:
        if std[4]=='Male': m_tut += 1
        else: f_tut += 1

    while tut:
        if len(tut)<team_size: break

        m = f = 0
        cgpa = 0
        schools = {i:0 for i in school}

        team = []
        for i in range(2):
            if m_tut>f_tut: k = fetch_std(tut,gender='Female')
            else: k = fetch_std(tut,gender='Male')
            team.append(k)
            tut.remove(k)

        # fetch and append
        while len(team)<team_size:
            for std in team:
                # school
                schools[std[2]] += 1
                # gender
                if std[4]=='Male': m+=1
                else: f+=1
                # cgpa
                cgpa += float(std[5])

            school_bl = [i for i in schools if schools[i]>1]

            if m>3: team.append(fetch_std(tut,gender='Female',schools=school_bl))
            elif f>3: team.append(fetch_std(tut,gender='Male',schools=school_bl))
            else: team.append(fetch_std(tut,schools=school_bl))
            
            # remove selected team members from the pool
            for k in team:
                if k in tut: tut.remove(k)

        for i in team: fo.write(','.join(i)+'\n')
        fo.write('\n')
        
fo.close()


Result

Teams with undesirable gender ratios (4+ of same gender) :  73
Teams with five of the same gender :  42
Teams with undesirable school ratios (3+ from same school) :  15
Total teams : 1200

I mean out of 1200 that's pretty good but I have no idea how to reduce this further, especially for the 5 gender teams. Everything I try seems to accidentally increase these numbers.
